# How do you leave a review on the Google Play Store without a Google+ account?

Tags: google-play-store, feedback

I would like to leave reviews for some of the Android apps I really appreciate.  But leaving reviews on the Google Play Store requires signing up for Google+.  Like many others, I refuse to add Google+ (or any social network) to my Google account.

So I thought I would just sign up for another empty Google account, and add Google+ to that.  Problem solved.  Or so I thought.  When I tried to leave the first review, Google Play Store refused to let me leave the review, saying that I hadn't installed the app yet.  Furthermore, it said that the account wasn't associated with any devices.  Ugh.

Most of the apps are free apps and a few are ones I have purchased.

I've noticed that many people have simply chosen to never leave reviews ever since Google made the poor decision to require a Google+ account in order to leave a review on the Play Store.

Is there a way to easily do what I am trying to accomplish?

BTW, before anyone asks, no, I'm not trying to leave more than one review for any app.  I just want to leave a positive review for the apps I enjoy using.

Comment: I don't think it is possible.

Comment: I totally share your concern – and I'm one of those who stopped leaving comments/ratings the day Google enforced G+ for that. Unfortunately, unless Google takes back that step, there won't be a work-around (at least no legal one).

Answer (score 4):

Sadly at present, you cannot. Since around November 2012 Google require Google Plus to review on the play store. All reviews are in your name, have your G+ picture and are publicly shared.

There is a popup that states:

> From now on, reviews you write will be posted publicly using your Google+ name and picture.
>
> Your name on previous reviews will appear as "A Google User".

Comment: Old answer. As of August 2016, a G+ Profile is **no longer required** to leave comments in Play Store.

Answer (score 1):

If your device supports multiple Google account you may try to add the new account and then  leaving a review from the new account.

Comment: If even then, Google+ is still required for the account from which you want to add review. Doesn't it?

Comment: Yes, but the idea is that the review would be made from the Google+ account that is connected to the secondary Google acount rather than the primary account.

Comment: Does this technique require installing the app from the other account?